# Openwrt: Package Makefile y el Error "make[4]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found."

Tags: linux, makefile

Estoy tratando de crear un paquete de instalación para OpenWrt. [Hay un supuesto tutorial con un ejemplo en la pagina oficial ][1], intentando recrearlo me ha resultado imposible por los constantes errores, buscando esos errores encontré esta pregunta [openwrtwhat-can-i-do-to-package-bin-files-into-ipk-packages?][2] en la cual te explican como realizar un ejemplo muy concreto, teniendo ese ejemplo y el anterior como base diseñe mi Makefile:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=modbus
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=0

# This specifies the directory where we're going to build the program.
# The root build directory, $(BUILD_DIR), is by default the build_mipsel
# directory in your OpenWrt SDK directory
PKG_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)


include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/modbus
    CATEGORY:=test
    TITLE:=modbus
    DEPENDS:=+libstdcpp
endef

define Package/modbus/description
    modbus interface
endef


define Package/modbus/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/bandwidth-client $(1)/mod
endef

# This line executes the necessary commands to compile our program.
# The above define directives specify all the information needed, but this
# line calls BuildPackage which in turn actually uses this information to
# build a package.
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,modbus))
```

Tras esto lo añadí con el comando **./scripts/feeds update -i && ./scripts/feeds install modbus** y lo añadió con éxito, si se realiza un make menuconfig se puede encontrar en la sección test y marcarlo para su compilación.

La estructura del paquete es la siguiente (dentro de /feeds/packages/utils/modbus), por un lado el Makefile y por otro la carpeta src/bandwidth-client y mi objetivo es que todo esto me genere un ipk que instale bandwidth-client en la carpeta /mod del dispositivo. bandwidth-client ya esta compilado.

El problema se encuentra a la hora de la compilación, en el momento del make siempre me lanza el siguiente error :

`make[3] -C feeds/packages/utils/modbus compile`

```
make[4]: Entering directory `openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/modbus'
make[4]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Es como si siempre tratara de recompilarlo y no encontrase un Makefile en target-mipsel_24kc_musl/modbus. Cuando segun lo que pone deberia simplemente crear el ipk.

Actualización: si dentro de la carpeta SRC añado el Makefile el error pasa a ser :

```
make[4]: Entering directory `openwrt/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/modbus'
make[4]: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

make package/modbus/compile
[1]: https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/packages
[2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662534/openwrtwhat-can-i-do-to-package-bin-files-into-ipk-packages?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Se puede definir compile como vacío, de esta manera eliminamos el error. Además es necesario editar el $(1)/mod inicial para que se genere el directorio.

```
define Build/Compile
endef 

#please note the changes with respect your file  
define Package/modbus/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/mod
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/src/bandwidth-client $(1)/mod
endef
```