# Makefile: no se instalan en el directorio correcto

Tags: linux, makefile

Siguiendo la pregunta [openwrt-package-makefile](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386159/openwrt-package-makefile-y-el-error-make4-no-targets-specified-and-no-m) : me he encontrado con el siguiente problema, resulta que tengo el siguiente Makefile para un paquete de OpenWrt :

```
define Build/Compile 
endef 
define Package/modbus/install 
  $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/modbus 
  $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/bandwidth-client $(1)/modbus 
  $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/modbus-mipsel $(1)/modbus 
  $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/modbus.db $(1)/modbus 
  $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/modbus.lua $(1)/modbus 
  $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/normal.lua $(1)/modbus 
  $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/modbusmodule.lua $(2)/usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/admin 
  $(INSTALL_DIR) $(3)/usr/lib/lua/luci/view/modbusmodule 
  $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/modbus.htm $(3)/usr/lib/lua/luci/view/modbusmodule 
  $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/service.htm $(3)/usr/lib/lua/luci/view/modbusmodule 
endef
```

la cuestión es que compila perfectamente y se crea el ipk sin problema, pero los archivos que tienen que instalarse en /usr/lib/lua/luci/view/modbusmodule y /usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/admin no se instalan, mientras que los de /modbus no dan problema alguno. No manda ningún mensaje de error durante la instalación y no encuentro una guía de creación de Makefile que me solucione la duda.

Comment: pueda que sea por problemas de usuario dado que estas intentando modificar **/usr/lib/** y para esos directorios debes estar logueado como administrador o solicitar dichos permisos.

Comment: Se supone que la instalación se realiza con permiso de super usuario. En realidad todas las instrucciones se ejecutan como superusuario puesto que es sobre un Arduino, osea que la instalación tiene que ser con esos permisos no ?

Answer (score 0):

Estaba mal declarado el $(INSTALL_DIR)

```
define Package/modbus/install
        $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/mod $(1)/usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/admin $(1)/usr/lib/lua/luci/view/modbusmodule
    
        $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/src/bandwidth-client $(1)/mod
        $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/src/modbusmodule.lua $(1)/usr/lib/lua/luci/controller/admin
        $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/src/service.htm $(1)/usr/lib/lua/luci/view/modbusmodule
    endef
```

Sobre el tema de los permisos resulta que siempre lo instala con los permisos 755 entonces se puede modificar el fichero que lo necesite con chmod.